# View is not shown for singleton ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a wpf application using Caliburn.Micro 2.0.1 and I found strange behaviour of Caliburn.Micro. In latest 3.0.3 it exists too.

Super simple project to reproduce bug: https://github.com/ihtfw/CaliburnMicroBug

MainWindowViewModel is Conductor for Screens.
There are two ScreenViewModel as Items for MainWindowViewModel with property SingletonViewModel.
In MainViewModel I can switch to first ScreenViewModel or second one.

Everything works perfect except that View for SingletonViewModel is shown only on Second ScreenViewModel after switching to second screen.

To reproduce:

- Start app
- Switch to Second screen
- Switch back to first screen
- View for SingletonViewModel is not shown =(

How to fix this?

**Update**

It's not possible to make these with ContentControl. Should use explicit view. In this case SingletonView and set DataContext of it. To wire up Caliburn.Micro actions bind them without context. So result will be:

```
<local:SingletonView DataContext={Binding Path=SingletonViewModel} cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the other answers you cannot have a "singleton view", the xaml UI model will not allow the same UI elements to be in the visual tree twice.

What you can do however is have two instances of the same view bound to the view model.

To do this you'll need to sidestep a feature of the framework.

Internally any view model which implements `IViewAware` holds a weak reference to the view, any time the framework tries to locate the view for a view model it first queries to the view model for that reference.

If a reference is returned then the view is removed from it's existing location and inserted into the new location.

In order to stop this can you do one of three things:

1. Have your `SingletonViewModel` not inherit from something that implements `IViewAware` such as `PropertyChangedBase`.
2. Do something really hacky and null out the attached view with the first code sample below.
3. Change `ViewLocator.LocateForModel` to remove this behavior with the second code sample below.

*Hacky null out view*

```
protected override void OnViewAttached(object view, object context)
{
    Views[context ?? ViewAware.DefaultContext] = null;
}
```

*Remove `IViewAware` behavior*

```
ViewLocator.LocatorForModel = (model, location, context) => ViewLocator.LocateForModelType(model.GetType(), location, context);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on your project and found out that your problem is in MainWindows constructor. Change MainWindow's constructor like below:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
    {


        Items.Add(new ScreenViewModel
        {
            DisplayName = "Screen 1",
            SingletonViewModel = new SingletonViewModel()
        });

        Items.Add(new ScreenViewModel
        {
            DisplayName = "Screen 2",
            SingletonViewModel = new SingletonViewModel()
        });

        ActiveItem = Items.First();
    }
```

Comment: Yes it would work, but SingletonViewModel should be singleton! And after your change it's not.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a Bug.

A `UIElement` such as a `UserControl` can only have one logical parent.

You are creating two `ScreenViews`, and you are trying to add the same  `SingletonView` to both of them, which is not possible, because `SingletonView` cannot have two parents.

Comment: Each ScreenView has it's own SigletonView and SingletonViewModel is just DataContext. Why is that not possible with Caliburn.Micro? If i wrote 
        <local:SingletonView DataContext="{Binding Path=SingletonViewModel}"></local:SingletonView>
        <local:SingletonView DataContext="{Binding Path=SingletonViewModel}"></local:SingletonView> it's ok. But <local:SingletonView cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=SingletonViewModel}"></local:SingletonView>
        <local:SingletonView cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=SingletonViewModel}"></local:SingletonView> would not work

Comment: Each screen yes... But you have a ContentControl which hosts a SingletonView, and you are only creating one instance of that View, simply not possible. If you want a single instance of a ViewModel to be DataContext of two Views, then you have to use another approach.